# FutureProvider gets data but returns Null

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm attempting to update user data after a process in my app. To achieve this, I am using the login function again to retrieve updated data from the database. However, I am encountering an issue where, when I use a `FutureProvider` in conjunction with an API call, the API successfully returns the data, but it's returning `null` (I can confirm this through debugging).

Here's my `userUpdateFetcher`, which is nearly identical to the `loginFetcher`, except this time I retrieve the email and password from the `userProvider` (where I store all user data):

```
final userUpdateFetcher = FutureProvider<User?>((ref) async {
  final userEmail = ref.watch(userProvider)!.email;
  final password = ref.watch(userProvider)!.password;

  try {
    final data = await UsersApi.login(userEmail, password);
    ref.refresh(userProvider.notifier).update((state) {
      return data;
    });
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    rethrow;
  }
});
```

This is the login code:

```
static Future<User?> login(String userEmail, String password) async {
    final dio = Dio();
    final url = Constants.baseUrl;
    try {
      final response = await dio.get('$url/users/login/$userEmail/$password');
      return User.fromJson(response.data);
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Error');
    }
}
```

Is this the best approach for updating user data, or is there a more efficient method?

Comment: I'm completely confused by this code, and that's rare.  What is the purpose of userUpdateFetcher?  What is its state? What watches it?  Why is it updating another provider?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I'm trying to update the user data after a process in my app, I do this by calling userUpdateFetcher that does an API call to retrieve all the user data. The userProvider stores all the user data in it.